# JQuery smooth content sliding

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MBMP/).

```
<div id="w">
    PARENT
    <div id="a" style="display:none">
        child 1
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        child 2
    </div>
</div>
----------------
$('#a').slideToggle('slow');
$('#b').slideToggle('slow');
```

The problem is that the height of parent container is a bit jumping while sliding children.
This is because animation of child divs is not synchronized.
**How can I make this animation smooth?**
Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way you can fix this would be to set a fixed height on your container

Comment: It is possible for sure via custom animations. I just want someone who has done it already :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4MBMP/34/)

You need to give fixed `height` to parent div.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because it isn't a margin issue.

Comment: Then which type of problem you have? Can you describe in more details?

Comment: @SanketS when the `slideToggle()` occurs, the parent element jumps slightly

Comment: It may be hard to notice - it's just 1 pixel or so.

Comment: @disfated please see my edited Answer. and see JSFiddle Demo.

Comment: I can't set fixed height. It would be too easy :)